# How to pass LocalDate as an argument?

Tags: java, string, char, java-time, localdate

I am trying to use the `LocalDate` Java class and passing it as a parameter in the method. When I am instantiating the method in main method I need to pass the `LocalDate` as an argument, when I try `'2019-08-16'` it says too many literals, when I try `"2019-08-16"` it says cannot be applied to `String`.

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class LocalDateExample {
    public void localDate(LocalDate date) {
        String dayOfMonth = Integer.toString(date.getDayOfMonth());
        System.out.println("Day Of Month is" + dayOfMonth); // this throws error
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateExample dd = new LocalDateExample();
        dd.localDate("2019-08-16"); // this line throws error
    }
}
```

Comment: You were close! Because your `localDate` method accepts a `LocalDate`, you can't pass a `String` (`"2019-08-16"`) to it. Instead, you'll first need to create a `LocalDate` using the `String`, like so: `LocalDate.parse("2019-08-16")`

Comment: `dd.localDate(LocalDate.parse("2019-08-16"));`?

Comment: `'2019-08-16' it says too many literals` suggests that you are using more advanced language features without grasping language basics like available *types*. For instance `char` type represents *character* and its *value* can be created like `'a'`, for instance `char someCharacter = 'a';`. Note that `char` can represent only *one* character at a time, so we can't write `char someCharacter = 'ab';` because those are two characters. For now my advice would be to start learning Java from basics, then moving to object-oriented concepts.

Comment: Thank you Jacob, Dan and Pshemo, it worked

Comment: This question is perfectly reproducible and was caused by no typo whatsoever. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
    dd.localDate(LocalDate.of(2019, Month.AUGUST, 16));
```

### Why so?

Since your method is declared to accept a `LocalDate` argument, you need to pass an instance of `LocalDate` (not a string or any other type). Java doesn’t have automatic type conversions, which is why it didn’t work with a string.

`LocalDate` and the other types of java.time have factory methods for creating objects. The most commonly used factory methods are simply named `of`. `LocalDate` has got two overloaded `of` methods. For most purposes I prefer to use the one accepting a `Month` enum constant as the middle argument as shown in the above example. The other one accepts an `int` for the month number (from 1 = January), so the following works too:

```
    dd.localDate(LocalDate.of(2019, 8, 16));
```

By the way with `'2019-08-16'` you had got a different problem since single quotes `'` are used for character literals. `'2'` is a character literal, but it needs to denote one character, so you are not allowed to have more characters between the single quotes.

Finally despite the comment in your code the following line does not cause any error (so I have corrected the comment here):

```
    System.out.println("Day Of Month is" + dayOfMonth); // this works fine
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I would recommend to consider renaming the function `localDate()`, especially when it asks for a `LocalDate` parameter:

```java
public class LocalDateExample {
    public void localDate(LocalDate date) {
        String dayOfMonth = Integer.toString(date.getDayOfMonth());
        System.out.println("Day Of Month is " + dayOfMonth);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateExample dd = new LocalDateExample();
        dd.localDate(LocalDate.parse("2019-08-16"));
    }
}
```

Should work, as the comments suggest.